# Intent Capture and Authenticate (Design of Intents and Calling Webhook)

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are designing an app, where it has the following:

Welcome Intent - Typical Greeting Message, when the conversation starts.
Intent 1 - Where is it more of authentication, User would be asked about certain credentials
Intent 2 - The functionality of asking a service like booking some food for home delivery. This intent has a series of mandatory questions with prompts defined which are being captured in parameter values.

Scenario 1 (more of a Happy Scenario):
User starts conversing, App/Agent asks about credentials
User provides credentials: App/Agent - invokes a webhook, verifies (from Intent 1) If not right user, provides a message of getting him/her registered/active
App/Agent - invokes the next starting of Intent 2 and gets values for his questions.
This is fine.

Scenario 2: 
User starts conversing, App/Agent asks about credentials 
User can always say a query (not the credentials) and put a query which can invoke Intent 2

How can we make sure that the series of questions which is within Intent 2 does not get invoked until & unless Intent 1 is not covered( that user is authenticated). From an user experience standpoint, the solution should not have all the user queries asked and then invokes the Webhook for Intent 2, then say you are not authenticated. That will not all be good User experience?
How do we handle this design problem while configuring dialog flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow's context feature is meant to control which intents can be matched at what point in the conversation.  You can set a output context for intent1 of "loggedin" and add a input context to intent2 with the same value "loggedin".

After intent1 has been matched a context of "loggedin" will be added to the conversations state.  intent2 can only be matched when the conversation has the "loggedin" context added to it.  This ensures that intent2 is only matched *after* intent1 has been matched in the conversation.  You can see screenshots of this setup below.

More about context in this blog post: https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/how-contexts-and-followup-intents-work/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Understood, read the link as well. 

I have defined that context for Output Context for Intent 1 and same for Input for Intent 2. In fact, in Intent 1, the user credentials are also captured Intent 1.

Now when you are saying - If I type a query for Intent2 (without providing details for INtent2 ), it not going to the mandatory right questions, which is fine, but it needs to give a configured response that please enter authentication details. Do we need to define a cusotm fallback intent for Intent 2?

Comment: You can create another fallback intent and add input contexts to if it you want to respond to users who after loggedin and are haven't trouble, but their is no obligation to do so.  If you don't create a fallback intent with a input context the fallback intent without any input contexts will be matched